# Regex - extract last term between _ and before . from path

Tags: regex, hive, impala

This is the regex that I'm currently testing

```
[\w\. ]+(?=[\.])
```

My ultimate goal is to include a regex expression to extract using **regexp_extract** in Impala/Hive query.

```
regexp_extract(col, '[\w\. ]+(?=[\.])', 1)
```

This doesn't work in Impala however.

Examples of path to extract from:

```
D:\mypath\Temp\abs\device\Program1.lua
D:\mypath\Temp\abs\device\SE1_Test-program.lua
D:\mypath\Temp\abs\device\Test_program.lua
D:\mypath\Temp\abs\device\Device_Test_Case-general.lua
```

The regex I've tested extracts the term I'm looking for but it's not good enough, for the second and third, fourth cases I would need to extract only the part after the last underscore.

[image]

My expections are:

```
Program1
Test-program
program
Case-general
```

Any suggestions? I'm also open to using something other than regexp_extract.

Comment: Like this? `[a-zA-Z0-9.=-]+(?=\.)` https://regex101.com/r/yeu7vW/1

Comment: I've edited the question, probably something such as that except that I need to run it in Impala/Hive environment.

Comment: I do not think Impala regex supports lookarounds. Use `([^-\\]+)\.\w+$` and grab Group 1 contents. Something like `regexp_extract(col, '([^-\\\\]+)\\.\\w+$', 1)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8HGJoE/1).

Comment: Then you can use `([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\\.` with a capture group and [regexp_extract](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_extract) See https://regex101.com/r/yavrNw/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, if I run that in Impala then it only extracts the drive e.g. D or G.

Comment: @Geosphere I think you have to double escape the dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Impala regex does not support lookarounds, and thus you need a capturing group to get a submatch out of the overall match. Also, if you use escaping `\` in the pattern, make sure it is doubled.

You can use

```sql
regexp_extract(col, '([^-_\\\\]+)\\.\\w+$', 1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8HGJoE/2).

The regex means

- `([^-_\\]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `-`, `_` and `\`
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It misses the third and another case. For example if I have D:\mypath\Temp\abs\device\Char_Satu.lua, then it captures Char_Satu but I only want to extract Satu.

Comment: @Geosphere Your examples are misleading. If you need all after last `_` AND `-`, use ``'([^-_\\\\]+)\\.\\w+$'``. I updated the answer, I hope it is finally what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\w` also matches an underscore, instead you can use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` instead.

Add matching a dot and hyphen in the character class, capture that in group 1 and match the expected trailing dot.

Note that you don't have to escape dots in a character class.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)[.]
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/4N4wXp/1)

Example using [regexp_extract](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_extract) where the `, 1` gets the group 1 value:

```
regexp_extract(col, '([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)[.]', 1)
```

If it should be at the end of the string only, matching the last dot without matching any backslashes in between:

```
 regexp_extract(col, '([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)[.][^\\\\.]+$', 1)
```